# Passive voice using the preposition "with" instead of "by"

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice

wiktionary.org offers

> Verb smite: 6. (figuratively, now only in passive) To strike with love
>   or infatuation.
>
> *Bob was smitten with Laura from the first time he saw
>    her*.

I wonder whether this **smitten** is rather an adjective at least syntactically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***smitten***

> **adjective**... deeply affected with or struck by strong feelings of attraction, affection, or infatuation
>
> Smite...smote...smitten ...
> It's an old-fashioned word that most modern English users encounter only in literature, and especially in older translations of the Bible, such as the King James Version:

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smitten)

> **adjective**...having suddenly started to like or love something or someone very much

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smitten)

And [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/smitten)

I would tend towards considering it adjectival. The original sense of the word as active verb has lost currency, and mainly seen in KJV Bible and other texts of the time. This looks like it has evolved into a simple adjective + preposition collocation to me.